# Order of dodecahedron automorphism group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics

I need to find out how many elements are in the automorphism group of a regular dodecahedron.

So Using Orbit-Stabilizer theorem I get $|G|=|G_x||O_x|$

If we pick a point on the wall of the dodecahedron we can rotate every wall $5$ different ways and the point on that wall would not change it's coordinates, so that's our stabilizer. Also we can rotate each wall so that it would 'become' one of the other $12$ walls, so that's our orbit.

In the end it's $5*12=60$. But wikipedia states that it's $120$, so I'm probably missing something here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like your argument only counts the rotations of the dodecahedron.  The automorphism group includes both rotations and reflections.

Comment: How many reflections are that that 'preserve' the dodecahedron?

Comment: There ought to be another $60$.  You can use roughly the same argument to analyze the full group, you just need to count the reflections that are in the stabilizer.